# Yii2 SwiftMailer sends mails twice

Tags: php, email, yii, swiftmailer

I write a game for football fans. So, I have to send similar mails to a group of people (not completely duplicated e-mail copies).
When I send the mails in a cycle - Yii framework sends the mails twice.
I suppose - it is because of the static variable Yii::$app.
Can someone give me a hint, please.
A code for example.

```
foreach ($oRace->user as $currUser) {
        $htmlContent = $this->renderPartial('start_race', ['oRace' => $oRace]);
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setFrom('info@example.com')
                ->setTo($currUser->mail)
                ->setSubject('Race "' . $raceName . '" has Started')
                ->setHtmlBody($htmlContent)
                ->send();
    }
```

Thanks all in advance!

My Mailer config.

```
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'mail.example.eu',
            'username' => 'support@example.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'TLS',
        ]
    ],
```

One more thing. The last mail in the cycle is never duplicated (only the last).

Another failed option.
Yii::$app->mailer->sendMultiple($allMails);

Comment: May be some logical error in your code costing you 2 mails.

Comment: check the content of $oRace   ..

Comment: I have made many tests. Everything looks good. Can I get a separate instance of the mail class?

Comment: What is your configuration on config/web.php??

Comment: Did you use a debug tool to see if you have a user duplicate on your loop?

Comment: moplin - Yes, I did.

Comment: Same here in dev enviroment. I'm using Mailhog, and you?

Comment: Talma - I did not made any automated test. I can try with Mailhog, as you do. Thank you.

Comment: Have you used papercut fake server, it might help you debugging this. Also in the form that triggers the email, are you using ajax?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use CC or BCC option in the email instead of using `foreach` loop to send emails. I hope this will help someone.

```php
$email = [];

foreach ($oRace->user as $currUser) {
    $email[] = $currUser->mail;
}

$htmlContent = $this->renderPartial('start_race', ['oRace' => $oRace]);
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom('info@example.com')
            ->setCc($email) // If you're using Bcc use "setBcc()"
            ->setSubject('Race "' . $raceName . '" has Started')
            ->setHtmlBody($htmlContent)
            ->send();
```

Comment: Thank you Shifrin. My case was too complicated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862124/how-to-send-mail-to-multiple-recipients-in-yii2-mailer-or-how-to-add-setcc-in-yi/29916410
You can find more options here. Regards

Comment: what if you want to send with a "Dear Username"?

Comment: @PhemeloKhetho You should use a mail template (view file) located under `@app/mail` by default. Then you can use it in the following way:

`Yii::$app->mailer->compose('template-name', ['username' => $username]);`

Comment: @Shifrin Maybe you didn't understand my question properly. My Question is; Is it possible to send an email using the `cc` or `bcc` field while still customizing the salutation to each individual recipient, such as addressing them by their name with 'Dear Recipient Name', or is this not possible with `cc` or `bcc`?

Comment: @PhemeloKhetho Where do you want to address 'Dear Recipient Name'? In the subject or in the body of the email or elsewhere?

Comment: I found the following code block from the Yii documentation, see whether it can help to solve your problem.

$messages = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $messages[] = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        // ...
        ->setTo($user->email);
}
Yii::$app->mailer->sendMultiple($messages);

Answer (score 1):

From the provided code snippets, there are 3 possible reasons for that. Either:

- `$oRace->user` contains every user twice
- `$currUser->mail` contains the email twice like `email@example.com;email@example.com"
- something is wrong inside the send function of SwiftMailer

Answer (score 1):

After all - I have  found that the issue was not with my Yii2 framework, but with my hosting mail server.
I have used https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut for listening what my framework sends. It receives mails on port 25, while it listens for events on port 37804. It's a little bit confusing. Yii2 web.php simple configuration for local mail server is:

```
$config = [
    'components' => 
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'localhost', // '127.0.0.1'
                'port' => '25',
            ]
        ],
    ],
];
```

Thank of all, who have read my post!